# Convert from pointer-to-member template function to functional type objects

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this code that works already:

```
// mem_fun example
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

struct C
{
    C(int i): y_(i) {};
    int y_;
    string op1(int x)
    {
       std::ostringstream oss;
       oss << "operation 1: " << x+y_;
       return oss.str();
    }
    string op2(string x)
    {
       std::ostringstream oss;
       oss << "operation 2: " << x << "+" << y_;
       return oss.str();
    }
};

struct container: map<string, C> 
{
// doesn't compile
// void safeOperation(string key, ??? bound_function_and_arg_object )

    template< typename argType >
    void safeOperation(string key, string (C::*mf)(argType a), argType a)
    {
        iterator it = find(key);
        if (it != end())
        {
            C* pC = &(it->second);

            cout << (pC->*mf)(a) << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "key: " << key << " missing\n";
        }
    }
};


int main () {
    container objects;

    objects.insert(container::value_type("a1", C(1)));
    objects.insert(container::value_type("b2", C(2)));
    objects.insert(container::value_type("c3", C(3)));

    objects.safeOperation("a1", &C::op1, 1);    
    objects.safeOperation("b2", &C::op1, 2);    
    objects.safeOperation("d4", &C::op1, 4);    
    objects.safeOperation("c3", &C::op2, string("3"));    

  return 0;
}
```

I'd like to change the template function on the map to use std::mem_fun and to bind the parameters together with the operation, rather than specify them as separate parameters to safeOperation.

In other words, I'd prefer to call safeOperation similar to this:

```
// wrong, but hopefully communicates what I'm trying to do:
objects.safeOperation(someKey, bind(&C::op1, 4));
```

The sample code is here: http://cpp.sh/74pgb

I'm probably missing something simple, but appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `bind` a member function, the first argument has to be an instance of the class whose member function it is. So what you want to do is generalize `safeOperation` to take any function that can be called on a `C*`:

```
template< typename F >
void safeOperation(string key, F func) {
    iterator it = find(key);
    if (it != end())
    {
        C* pC = &(it->second);

        cout << func(pC) << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "key: " << key << " missing\n";
    }    
}
```

And then generate your `func`s by `bind`ing with the argument, but also leaving a placeholder:

```
using namespace std:;placeholders;
objects.safeOperation("a1", std::bind(&C::op1, _1, 1));
//                                             ^^
//                                    placeholder for pC
```

Comment: Ok, that works and makes sense, but I'm a little surprised there isn't a member-function specific form of bind that assumes the placeholder since it seems tedious to constantly repeat it....?

Comment: @BitBlitz You could write one. It's a pretty specific use-case to want to bind just the arguments but not the instance for a member function, and it's only a couple lines to do it.

Comment: I tried to write one. I came up with something that works on my GCC 4.6 compiler, but doesn't work on CPP.SH.  Details in the question above.

Comment: @BitBlitz Don't edit your question to be a different question. Ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 1):

`boost/std::bind` create an object with an implementation-specific type. The only requirement is that the object is callable using `operator()`.

To handle any functional objects you can change your function template in the following way:

```
template< typename F >
void safeOperation(string key, F f)
{
    // ...
        cout << f(pC) << "\n";

// ...
objects.safeOperation("someKey", bind(&C::op1, placeholders::_1, 4));
```

That should enable almost the syntax you require.